# how to use Java 9 zulu from sdkman?

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans, update-alternatives, ubuntu-make

Netbeans is using JDK 8 per the source or binary format as shown here:

[image: source or binary format]

How do i switch to zulu, which is 9?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 9.0.0.15
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "9.0.0.15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu build 9.0.0.15+181)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu build 9.0.0.15+181, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Netbeans was installed through `umake` and zulu JDK 9 was installed through `sdkman`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main Netbeans window you have to go to:

```
Tools -> Java Platforms
```

and add JDK 9.

If you used sdkman to get Java JDK then the path will be `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-zulu` or similar (the path to `Platform Folder` in the screenshot below is different because I didn't use sdkman [to get the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/)).

[image]

If once you have done that you see nothing in the `Classes` tab it probably means you are using a Netbeans version without support for Java 9. Try with a [nightly build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/).

You can find more information regarding Netbeans Java 9 support on [this page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support).

Comment: hmm, having trouble with the sdk path as described above for jdk 14..